# Adding a submenu to the Tools menu returns tools.php in a popup box

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu, add-submenu-page

I am trying to add a submenu to the Tools menu.  When the custom Tools sub-menu is chosen, I want it to call a function.  That function will echo things out to the browser page that is loaded.  My code is like this:

1. Hook the function that will add a submenu to the Tools menu.

   ```
   add_action('admin_menu', 'create_tools_submenu');
   ```
2. The function that adds a submenu to Tools menu.

   ```
   function create_tools_submenu() {
       add_management_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'slug', 'generate_page_content' );
   }
   ```
3. The function that runs when my custom Tools submenu page is loaded.

   ```
   function generate_page_content() {
       echo some stuff to the page...
   }
   ```

The code is partially working.  A custom submenu is present under the Tools menu.  However, when I select it, instead of loading a new page with the output of my function, a standard "save" popup box appears, with the filename `tools.php` already in the "Save as" field.

When I look at the Codex entry for `add_management_page`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_management_page

it says that the return value is

> The resulting page's hook_suffix, or false if the user does not have
>   the $capability required.

I understand that, in my case, the resulting page's hook_suffix is `tools.php`, and that is the exact name of the file that appears in the popup "Save As" box when I run my code.  But I don't understand, why in the world my code is even generating a "Save As" popup box?  There is no where in my code that calls for a save pop up box, so... where is it coming from?  Does `add_management_page()` always create a "Save As" popup box?  I feel that I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks very much for any help.  I'm really stumped by this.

Comment: this popup may come from the function `generate_csv_page_content`. is there a header of content-type different from HTML ?

Comment: In `add_management_page` you have `generate_page_content`, but then you write the callback as `generate_csv_page_content`. That effectively means there is no callback function and you get unexpected results.

Comment: Yes there is a header.  In generate_page_content, I have the code:
 `header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');`
 `header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');`   I was given some of this code from a person I'm working with.  Those two `header` lines I simply copy and pasted from the code I was given.  I thought it was necessary.  The page I am generating should contain a link to a CSV file that can be downloaded.  I thought the `header` code had something to do with generating the CSV file.